# Как отсортировать список словарей по заданному порядку ключей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list, dict

мне нужно просортировать мой список словарей по заданному порядку ключей. У меня есть список словарей например:

```
[
  {"name": "Betty", "time_created": 1664573325, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1},
  {"name": "Walter", "time_created": 1664573325, "last_name": "Caruana", "premium": null, "gender": "female", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 2}
```

мне нужно его посорировать по заданному значению, например чтоб сначала был ключ name потом age и потом ip а не так как они представлены. Как это возможно сделать

Comment: почему у вас в заголовке написано одно, а в вопросе - другое? вам нужно отсортировать элементы словарей внутри списка, а не список словарей.

Comment: покажите код вашей попытки сделать. иначе вопрос будет закрыт

Comment: уже сделал, сам отвечу на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

вот решение задачи возможно кому-то пригодиться:

```
result = [{'name': obj['name'], 'time_created': obj['time_created'],  'gender': obj['gender'], 'age': obj['age'], 'last_name': obj['last_name'],  'ip': obj['ip'], 'city': obj['city'], 'premium': obj['premium'],  'birth_day': obj['birth_day'], 'balance': obj['balance'], 'user_id':  obj['user_id']} for obj in result]
keys = result[0].keys()
```